# adding date column to the appending output csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, append

I use this code below to combine all csv files : below each file has 10,000 rows :

billing_report_2014-02-01.csv
billing_report_2014-02-02.csv
:

```
fout=open("out.csv","a")
for num in range(1,10):
    print num
    for line in open("billing_report_2014-02-0"+str(num)+".csv"):
         fout.write(line) 
for num in range(10,29):
    print num
    for line in open("billing_report_2014-02-"+str(num)+".csv"):
         fout.write(line) 
fout.close()
```

but now I want to add new date column to the out.csv file how can I add date column and have value of "2014-02-01" to every row that I append billing_report_2014-02-01 to out.csv, and 
value of "2014-02-02" to every row that I append billing_report_2014-02-02 to out.csv  how can I approach this ?

Comment: @Nabla can you clarify that a little bit ? I am fairly new to python. Thanks

Comment: What I said is not really necessary in this case, I commented too fast. Nevertheless you might want to look up the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module, it helps working with csv files. There is also the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module, which would simplify your date formatting, see [`date.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List the filenames you want to work on, then take the data from that, build a generator over the input file that removes trailing new lines, and adds a new field with the date... eg:

```
filenames = [
  'billing_report_2014-02-01.csv',
  'billing_report_2014-02-02.csv'
]

with open('out.csv', 'w') as fout:
    for filename in filenames:
        to_append = filename.rpartition('_')[2].partition('.')[0]
        with open(filename) as fin:
            fout.writelines('{},{}\n'.format(line.rstrip(),to_append) for line in fin)
```

Comment: ok I get the bit about the filenames .. should have put that in myself.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just add the date at the end:

```
for line in open("billing_report_2014-02-0"+str(num)+".csv"):
     fout.write(line+',DATE INFORMATION')
```

I am presuming your CSV is really comma separated, if it is tab separted the characters should be \t

you could also use an intermediate step by changing line:

```
line = line + ', DATE INFORMATION'
```

as you are trying to add the file name date just add it per variable:

```
line = line + ', 2014-02-0'+ str(num//10)
```

you could use the replace function if it is always the ",LLC" string expression, see the example below

```
>>> string = "100, 90101, California, Example company,LLC, other data"
>>> string.replace(',LLC',';LLC')
'100, 90101, California, Example company;LLC, other data'
>>>
```

putting it all together and trying to bring some of the inspiration from @Jon CLements  in as well (KUDOS!):

```
def combine_and_add_date(year, month, startday, endday, replace_dict):
    fout=open("out.csv","a")
    for num in range(startday,endday+1):
        daynum = str(num)
        if len(daynum) ==1:
            daynum = '0'+daynum

        date_info = str(year+'-'month+'-'+daynum)
        source_name = 'billing_report_'+date_info+'.csv'

        for line in open(source_name):
            for key in replace_dict:
                line.replace(key,replact_dict[key])

            fout.write(line+','+date_info) 

    fout.close()
```

I hope this works and you should (hopefully I am a newb...) use it like this, note the dictionary is designed to allow you to make all kinds of replacements

```
combine_and_add_date("2014","02",1,28, {',LLC': ';LLC', ',PLC':';PLC'})
```

fingers crossed

Comment: I think he might want the actual date.

Comment: @2705114-john this is almost works , my file is comma separated but one under business columne there is some company that has "companyname,LLC."  so when I use the code above, the row that have company with ",LLC." would move furthur one extra column. how can I actually fix this ?